# Is it possible to tunnel a USB drive to a virtual guest machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, malware, usb-storage

Is it possible to tunnel a USB drive (thumb-drive, WD Passport, etc.) to a virtual guest machine, so that the host machine only sees the contents as raw data?

The application of this would be to more safely access a USB device that may or may not have malware included.

Note:

- I am not looking for USB passthrough, as that is allowing a guest machine to directly access host machine hardware.
- I simply want the data on a thumb-drive to be insulated from the host machine as it passes to the virtual machine.
- I am using VirtualBox (just in case there are some vendor-specific solutions)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible and easy.

- Plug the USB stick (or whatever USB peripherial you want) into a linux box (could be something like [this](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/nexx/wt3020#dokuwiki__top) for $15), this part is completely under your control
- Configure and run a `usbip` server
- In your client install the `usbip` client drivers
- Access your USB device via the network (not as a file share - as a raw USB device)
- Added bonus: This works exceptionally well to connect things like scanners, printers or USB-Serial adapters to a VM, i.e. bridge the virtual machine to physical world gap.
- for paranoia: Run the usbip session through an SSH tunnel